# How to use a generator expression in python to create a list of odd integers?

Tags: generator-expression

How would I go about changing the program below to a generator expression that yields the same result?

```
print 'this program creates a list of odd numbers in the range of your choice'
start_num=int(input('Enter Starting Number'))
end_num=int(input('Enter ending number'))
my_list=[]
for i in range(start_num,end_num+1):
    if i%2==1:
        my_list.append(i)
print ('odd numbers in the range', my_list)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
print("this program creates a list of odd numbers in the range of your choice.")

def generator():
     start_num=int(input("enter the starting number:"))
     end_num=int(input("Enter the ending number:"))
     odds=list(i for i in range(start_num,end_num+1)if i%2==1)
     print(odds)


if__name__=='__main__':
     generator()``
```

P.S. GOOD LUCK ON THE MIDTERM THIS WEEK!